# How can I make the OS X privilege escalation popup less annoying?

Tags: password

I am looking for a way to make the root privilege escalation procedure less annoying - I have to type the password too many times.

Is it possible to remember the password once per login session or to remember it for a specific period of time? Or to have the dialog but not require you to type the password?

Remark: I'm looking for GUI solution, for console `sudo` I do have a solution.

Comment: This sounds like a gaping security hole to me – If you don´t care about permissions (and thus security) you could just start working in the root user...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OS X's authorization rights and behaviours can be adjusted through the `/etc/authorization` file.

You must take care when altering this file; mistakes can lock you out of your Mac. There are instructions at the top of the file to get you started.

To extend the period of time authorization is granted, look for the appropriate `timeout` field and increase the value as needed.

Comment: I think that probably what I was looking for is after `<key>system.privilege.admin</key>`, I modified the timeout from 300 to 3600 - probably from 5min to 50min.

Comment: @Sorin Actually 3600 would be 60 minutes, not 50.